# CComboBox::GetLBText returns garbage

Tags: c++, mfc

I am filling a combobox:

```
    while((pHPSet = pHPTable->GetNext()) != NULL)
    {       
      CString str = pHPSet->GetName();
          // I am normally using str but to proove that this is 
          // not the problem I am using "a"
      m_comboBaseHP.AddString(_T("a"));
    }
```

Now I am trying to read the combobox:

```
if(m_comboBaseHP.GetCount() > 0)
{
    CString csHPName = _T("");
    m_comboBaseHP.GetLBText(0, csHPName);
    // This is the ms way but ReleaseBuffer causes a crash
    //CString str = _T("");
    //int n = m_comboBaseHP.GetLBTextLen( 0 );
    //m_comboBaseHP.GetLBText( 0, str.GetBuffer(n) );
    //str.ReleaseBuffer();

    // Do whatever with csHPName
}
```

The problem is that csHPName shows in the Debugger some Chinese signs. I am assuming this is memory garbage. This happens in the same Method. This happens pre draw. Post draw the same issue. This happens in Debug and Release. I don't understand how this can happen since I am not actually working with pointers.

Comment: please check any memory leak in your code

Comment: @kTekkie I appreciate your comment but this is a product with millions line of code and I am sure somewhere there are some. Could you please be more specific why I am looking for them. This is to generell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently it is necessary to set the property Has Strings of the combobox to True.

Comment: I am using a [customized](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/489189/Group-Combo-Box) Combobox and facing the same problem but I can't set *Has Strings* to `false`. Is there any other possible solution ?